# aws samba mount error: host is down

Tags: linux, windows, samba, mount

We have an AWS ami Linux (2017.03) EC2 instance with several shares hosted locally in our office mounted as folders with cifs. Mounting these drives always works, no problem.

/etc/fstab:

```
//<ip>/share  /mnt/xdrive cifs exec,iocharset=utf8,username=<username>,password=<pwd>
//<ip2>/share2  /mnt/ydrive cifs exec,iocharset=utf8,username=<username>,password=<pwd>
```

However, about half the time when I try to access the files on the shares, I get the error:

```
Host is down
```

The local servers are all running Windows Server 2012.

Sometimes if I unmount and remount the shares they start working again, and sometimes if I restart samba they start working again. They all eventually start working after some time.

What could cause this type of intermittent connectivity issue?

Could it be a problem with our Sophos in aws?

Comment: on 16.04 vers=1.0 seemed to help.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this has something related to patches delivered by windows updates to prevent ransom-ware attack. 
It seams the server which holds the shared folder rejects CIFS V1 requests. 
By default mount uses CIFS V1. give it a try by adding `vers=2.0` to the end of your mount command. 
I had the same problem and this way I manged to fix it. 
PS / FYI : my command looks as follows

```
//192.168.1.10/public/mount /media/windowsshare cifs credentials=/home/MY_USERNAME/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0 vers=2.0
```

Comment: I added the vers=2.0. Hopefully that will fix it, but due to it being intermittent I'll have to let it run for a while before I'll know. Thank you.